# how to return value to a label from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My code in

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowNewProfessionalWindow(UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel UOVM)
    {
        Guid OrguID=new Guid(UOVM.Org_UID);
        using (gcserpEntities context = new gcserpEntities())
        {
            var model = new UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel();
            //model.Org_UID = OrgUID;
            UOVM.org_name_long = context.organizations.Where(c => (c.organization_uid == OrguID)).FirstOrDefault().org_name_long;
            //model.IsAddProfessional = true;
            return View("Index", UOVM);
        }
    }
```

I want to return a value to a label. what code for my VIEW?

Comment: Instead of adding additional code in the comments below, update the question with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Displaying a value in a label can be done like this:

```
<label>@Model.MyProperty</label>
```

or, with HTML helper:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```

If that isn't enough, then you really need to clarify what your problem is.

---

As @Ingo has says, your need to define the class your are using as your view model. Put this at the top of your view:

```
@model UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel
```

Comment: add "@model <completeNamespace>.UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel" as first line in the view

Comment: my code in view is like this


@using (this.Html.BeginForm("ShowNewProfessionalWindow", "UpdateOrganizationUID"))
{        
     <div class="divContent">
    <h5>Organization UID:</h5> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Org_UID)
         <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="SubmitQuery()" class="login-button" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
     <div class="divContent">
      <h5>Name Long:</h5>
      @Html.EditorFor(x => x.name_long)
  

       @Html.LabelFor(x => x.name_long) 
         <label>@Model.Org_UID</label>
        
        
       </div>
         
        
}

Comment: I dont have any errors but It doesnt displaying value of my model to a label.

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

```
@model UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel 

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.org_name_long)`

Take a look at this also, for help with [Html Helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ViewBag.SomeTempFieldName = "your value"` or `ViewData.SomeTempFieldName = "your value"` and then access the value in view page using ViewBag.SomeTempFieldName or ViewData.SomeTempFieldName, in same way how you use model.SomeProperty

use this approach only when you have some specific piece of information needed to be passed from controller to view, don't use it if the value you are looking for is part of model of your view page, in that condition access using Model.Property name (i assume you know how to create models and associate/define for a view page)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

Imagine your model is as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view you can create label as follows:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
```

The above code will render the output as follows:

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>
```